# Adding a button to activity that opens a browser URL

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to add a button to one of my activities (that displays a news article), so when the user clicks the button the article is opened in their browser. So far I have added the button in my xml and it appears. I'm just having some trouble with the click listener. Below is my code, i'm getting an error for 'setOnClickListener' which is 'Non-static method 'setOnClickListener(android.view.View.onClickListener)' cannot be referenced from a static content.

I'm not sure what this means! maybe i'm not calling the method in the right place or there is just an error with the method itself?

Please could someone take a look, thanks!

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class NewsItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Declare java object for the UI elements
    private TextView itemTitle;
    private TextView itemDate;
    private TextView itemContent;
    private NetworkImageView itemImage;

    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_item);

        itemTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        itemDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemDate);
        itemContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemContent);
        itemImage = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.itemImage);

        EDANewsApp app = EDANewsApp.getInstance();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int itemId = intent.getIntExtra("newsItemId", 0);

        String url = "http://www.efstratiou.info/projects/newsfeed/getItem.php?id="+itemId;

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, listener, errorListener);

        app.requestQueue.add(request);

        Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                int itemId = intent.getIntExtra("newsItemId", 0);
                String shareUrl = "http://www.efstratiou.info/projects/newsfeed/getItem.php?id=" + itemId;

                Intent buttonIntent = new Intent();
                buttonIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                buttonIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                buttonIntent.setData(Uri.parse(shareUrl));
                startActivity(buttonIntent);
            }
        });
    };
```

activity_news_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NewsItemActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#3183b9"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemDate"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/itemImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20sp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/BrowserButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="View in browser"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                style="@style/BrowserButton"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... });
```

to

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BrowserButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... });
```

You need to call the `setOnClickListener` method on an instance of `Button`, not on the class itself.

Comment: He should create the object of `Button` out of `onCreate()` it might cause a NPE if he wants to use it somewhere... :)

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't really understand what this means?

Comment: @user3005003 see my answer I explained you how to do this.

Comment: @Skizo not necessarily. It depends on how he will use it. It's a better practice to declare variables locally if they're not going to be accessed by other class methods.

Comment: I know @Sparta but it's recomendable :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this :

```
 Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

You have to declare it out of `onCreate()` as you did with your `Textviews` as :

```
Button btn;
```

> Why?

Because if you put it on `onCreate()` you wont be able to use this object out of `onCreate()` so it's recomendable to put it as a public object.

Then in your `onCreate()` do this :

```
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BrowserButton);
```

Then you do the `OnclickListener()` as follows :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            int itemId = intent.getIntExtra("newsItemId", 0);
            String shareUrl = "http://www.efstratiou.info/projects/newsfeed/getItem.php?id=" + itemId;

            Intent buttonIntent = new Intent();
            buttonIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            buttonIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            buttonIntent.setData(Uri.parse(shareUrl));
            startActivity(buttonIntent);
        }
    });
```

> I'm still getting an error for onClickListener, saying it 'cannot resolve symbol'.

Make sure that you've imported this :

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
```

You can do it doing this :

Add `implements OnClickListener {` as follows :

```
public class NewsItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

Then on your `Button` you do this :

```
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BrowserButton);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then add a `switch case` as follows :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId()) {
  case R.id.BrowserButton:         
      Intent intent = getIntent();
            int itemId = intent.getIntExtra("newsItemId", 0);
            String shareUrl = "http://www.efstratiou.info/projects/newsfeed/getItem.php?id=" + itemId;

            Intent buttonIntent = new Intent();
            buttonIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            buttonIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            buttonIntent.setData(Uri.parse(shareUrl));
            startActivity(buttonIntent);
        }
      break;

}
```

}

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful and the explanation was useful. I'm still getting an error for onClickListener, saying it 'cannot resolve symbol'.

Comment: Have you imported `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`?

Comment: When I do it says it's unused

Comment: See if you have those three imports

Comment: Show me what imports are you using please

Comment: import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import com.android.volley.Response;

Comment: ahh sorry that's hideous! wasn't sure how to post it

Comment: If you don't want to do my second edit, remove the imports which contains `view` and then import it again using the alt + ctrl I think the problem is there

Comment: Got a lot of errors from implements onClickListener. 'class 'NewsItemActivity' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onClick(View)' in onClickListener

Comment: I meant `View.OnClickListener` and then it will ask to add the methods, then inside that `onClick()` method, you add the code

Comment: @user3005003 You should mark an answer as a correct if you solved it, if you did not feel free to ask me again ;)